# How to not get killed while in an enemy country?

Tags: apocalypse, survival

So, on a prototype deep sea submarine, a group of soldiers (sailors?) are on a mission to test out the new craft, when a nuclear war breaks out between two superpowers. They are out in the middle of the ocean, and they have a limited amount of rations. They're too far away from their home country to make it back, and only have the power reserves left to sail to the nearest country. The problem is, that nearest country is the other superpower that went to war with their home country. They are wearing their home country's military uniforms, and have their home country's accents, so there is no hiding where they're from. So, what is a way they could try not to get martyred in this country?

Comment: What is their training?  Are they trained to blend in to foreign cultures at all?  Also, what's left after the nuclear war?  There's a lot of people who argue that you wont have to worry about much government of anything.

Comment: @Cort Ammon: Their trained in controlling subs, using weapons, and survival training. The government back in their home country is collapsed already, but in the enemy country, the military still has a presence, and martial law has been instanted. They will shoot first ask questions later

Comment: What is on-board the sub?   A prototype submarine operating in unfriendly waters without support is highly unusual, so I'm guessing their equipment is unusual as well.  Items which may have value in a post-nuclear world for trading would be of particularly high usefulness.

Comment: Are both countries still intact after a nuclear war? Mutually ensured destruction usually means that nukes will never be used, and when they are both countries/powers will be destroyed and you probably won't need to worry about people when you will die from the fallout anyway.

Comment: @Cort Ammon: They have a water purifier, some weapons, power armor and etc.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific as to what world-based problem you're trying to solve - for example, are you looking for exploitable gaps in martial law as enforced by patrols? As is the answer boils down to 'what kind of story are you writing?'

Comment: @pingcode: exploitable gaps inj the martial law

Comment: Do their uniforms include white underwear? Then use it to create makeshift white flags and march towards the closest possible location of that hostile superpower's military and surrender to them. Pray that said military still adheres to Geneva (or whatever) convention and that you are not lynched by some angry civilians before you reach it.

Comment: It's hard to have Martial Law after an apocalypse. Who is going to pay and feed and equip all those soldiers after the centralized systems are nuked? Without pay or food, why would they remain instead of lighting out for the nearest farm country or fishing village to look for new jobs...or home to look for their families?

Comment: How in Scott's name did they manage to get that far off and that low on supplies? If they're military then there are contingencies and regulations on these kind of things, probably even getting below like 70% fuel reserves before turning to base should get them a court martial..!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty-close-to happened already: September 23-24, 1916. The German L-33 dirigible lost buoyancy due to battle damage over London and landed...in England. Without weapons, food, radio or hope of rescue.

The 22 skilled German naval aviators destroyed all they could of the airship's technology under the cover of darkness. They were within sight of the coast... but also within sight of a village that would wake up at dawn.

They formed up and marched across the English countryside before dawn, using darkness to hide their uniforms. The unarmed crew hoped to be mistaken for Home Guard in the dark, and to quietly steal a boat and cross the Channel back to friendly territory. Their leader spoke English without a German accent.

They did not find any boats before dawn exposed them, and surrendered without a fight to a local Constable on a bicycle, who was also unarmed and outnumbered 22-to-1. The German sailors were not martyred, but were properly held as POWs in accordance with generally accepted norms prevailing at the time.

Source: *Zeppelins of World War I* by Wilbur Cross, 1993, pp. 97-100.

Comment: Imagine being that constable. I would be sweating so hard

Comment: @Shadowzee sweating you say? You might as well surrender to them!

Answer (score 5):

"They're too far away from their home country to make it back"
**What were they supposed to do if nuclear war did not break out?**
Generally, submarines are all about stealth, so they carry supplies to do their mission and return to home base, without resupply (and sometimes without surfacing)

Were they planning to resupply at a friendly base at some island?
They can still go there. If their base is nuked, they can seek shelter with local population, or live off the land.

Were they planning to resupply at a ship that got nuked, with no plan B?  That's some very poor planning, especially for a test run.

A **more realistic setting** would be a first-of-its-kind submarine, on first combat mission to enemy shores,  who suffered some malfunction or accident that crippled its primary drive, and irradiated most of food supply.

This was the scenario in **Hunt for Red October**: they surrender, and trade their high-tech submarine and their knowledge of it, for their life and reasonable comforts. They can negotiate this deal using radio.
After they surrender, their captors have incentives to keep them alive and happy to use them in spying or propaganda, and to encourage further defectors. 
And the crew will be happy to defect since their "motherland" has sent them on what turned out to be a suicide mission.

If enemy follows **Geneva convention**, they can sink the submarine and surrender, and enjoy the rights guaranteed to POW's.

But I assume that enemy is either a rogue nation, or too scarred by nuclear war to act honorably.

With a bit of fishing and desalinization gear, they can **survive at sea for quite some time**. They can move to lifeboats, and use sails and currents to make way to friendlier waters. I am pretty sure every military vessel has the gear and supplies for that, and the crew has the training.

They can find a **civilian ship**, and ask for asylum, or hire them with gold from captain's emergency supplies, or highjack it, or just loot supplies and sink it. Submarines are real good at finding surface vessels. If they are taking over an enemy ship, they will have to capture it fast or stealthily enough to prevent its captain from radioing the mainland.

Or they can find a **place to hide on the shore**. An uninhabited island, an abandoned oil rig, or a small village that they take occupy with weapons, or hire with gold. In post-nuclear apocalypse, a small town might just hire them for protection from bandit raids. Then they can wait for rescue from homeland, or try to get a boat to leave.